# can i resolve "error MSB8009 without installing VS2008 SP1

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

can i resolve error MSB8009: .NET Framework 2.0/3.0/3.5 target the v90 platform toolset. Please make sure that Visual Studio 2008 is installed on the machine. without installing vs 2008 SP1 for visual cpp project

Comment: What does the .NET Framework online documentation says about it? Since it's online, I believe it's te most appropriate information source. If it still does not provide an answer, refer it and try again in SO.

Answer (score 6):

Your project is set to target the VC9/VS2008 toolset - if you want to build in using VC10/VS2010 without having VS2008 installed you need to target the VC10 toolset.

- Open the VS2010 solution file.
- Go to the project properties dialog, `Configuration Properties -> General`
- Change `Platform Toolset` from v90 to v100.

You will no longer be able to build using VS2008.